# Problem with an element in xml and kotlin [Gave a ID twice]

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout, android-activity

[Pastebin | Full xml file](https://pastebin.com/19WXRrDR)

[xml element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fIm4.png)

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/etBaseAmount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:ems="8"
    android:hint="Bill amount"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tvBaseLabel"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvBaseLabel"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tvBaseLabel" />
```

[Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aQfN.png)

Can someone say me what I did wrong?

I work with Android 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found the solution randomly: The problem was that for an unknow reason the element was twice in the file xD

Answer (score 2):

Remove (android:id=@+id/etBaseAmount") for the parent constraint layout(line #5) you have given same id two times

Answer (score 1):

In the xml link you've provided I can see that you have used the same id `(android:id="@+id/etBaseAmount")` for the parent constraint layout **(line #5)** as well as the `EditText` **(line #55)**, change the id for the parent layout and it will works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please attach full xml , looks like you are missing a parent tag

Comment: Did it, you can look now into the whole xml file

Comment: brother i can't open it for some reason may be edit the question and add it here